# Merging 2 Windows 8 Store App Projects

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

For a school project we developed 2 different projects (2 solutions). Now we need to merge them together to form 1 Windows 8 Store App.

I added Project2 to the solution of Project1. But I ran into some issues.

Each project has an `.appxmanifest-file`. If I keep both files, VS 2013 will complain because the logos are set in both projects. The error message is:

> Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path
>   'Assets\Logo.scale-100.png'...

I tried deleting 1 `.appxmanifest-file` but then VS complains about missing the file.
Deleting the logos out of 1 manifest also gives error messages.

How can I merge these 2 projects without these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can't.

This type of project is designed to work as standalone application so you can use them both in one solution.

What you should is to decide which one you want to leave as main project, then add "class library project" to this solution and import all needed files from the other solution

Comment: I feared it would be something like this... Thank you!

Comment: I have the same issue for my Test project, it's not a good to have a separated solution to run tests.